# How to correctly type my react context provider?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement a context provider in my react web app but the problem is that the typing is wrong. I'm expecting to have the type of User or null but the type is { }. The following code is the implementation of the context provider. How can I make it so that the context provider only returns a User or null?

```ts
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

interface User {
    username: string,
    id: number,
    token: string,
}

const AuthContext = createContext([{}, () => {}])

const AuthProvider = ({children}: {children: React.ReactNode} ) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
          if(sessionStorage.getItem('state')) {
              let x: string | null = sessionStorage.getItem('state')

              if (x !== null) {
                let y: User = JSON.parse(x!.toString())
                setUser(y)
              }
        }
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(user))
    }, [user])

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={[user!, setUser]}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider }
```

Comment: add a `console.log` after `let y: User = JSON.parse(x!.toString())` and see if you stored `{}`. Your code seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to type the context. Pass in a type variable to `createContext<TYPE>()`. It would look like this:

```
interface User {
  username: string
  id: number
  token: string
}

const AuthContext = createContext<
  [User | null, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<User | null>>]
>([null, () => {}])
```

You can see it in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-shape-g9o8f?file=/src/Auth.tsx:140-262).